# Vi for Cygwin syntax

Tags: vi, cygwin, syntax-highlighting

How can I make vi in Cygwin highlight the syntax when I open a file by default? I know that I can type in the command "syntax on" but I would prefer to not do this all the time.

Answer (score 4):

Put the line `syntax on` in your `~/.vimrc` (assuming you're talking about vim), same as on any other installation of vim.

Answer (score 0):

As Gilles says that add `syntax on` in your `~/.vimrc`. You can also add other such as `set nu` (the number of line), `set bacpspace=2` and so on. The `~/.vimrc` file is a configuration file, you can configure it the same way as on Linux.

Comment: I'm sorry, the file(.vimrc) is used to set vi editor as in Linux.

Comment: Ah ok Mat fixed it. I will delete the command.